# Creating a 404 page for ExpressionEngine

Tags: 404

How do you create a 404 page for Expression Engine? Does anyone have any tips or links to documentation or articles that cover this subject? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Have you [read the docs on 404 pages](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/404pages.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might read this article [Guide to 404 Pages with ExpressionEngine](http://joviawebstudio.com/index_ee.php/blog/guide_to_404_pages_with_expressionengine/)

It would help you great.

Comment: Many thanks for your input. I will check it out.

Comment: Archived link for EE2: https://web.archive.org/web/20121120233555/http://joviawebstudio.com/index_ee.php/blog/guide_to_404_pages_with_expressionengine/

Answer (score 0):

That article is definitely handy, but it is not recommended that you Run PHP (security risks, can't cache templates, etc...) in your templates. So I definitely would not do that. In order to pass the appropriate HTML headers look at:

[http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/http-header][1]

You would simply add: `{exp:http_header status="404"}` to your 404 template.

Hope that helps as well.

NB - if you throw this error via {if no_results} - as you normally do maybe? - you get 404 headers without needing PHP or an addon... see http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#if-no-results

Comment: Please, complete the answer of Bhashkar, so, instead of post another one.